# argparse Python modules in cli

Tags: python, linux, command-line, argparse

I am trying to run a python script from the Linux SSH Secure Shell command line environment, and I am trying to import the argparse library, but it gives the error: "ImportError: No module named argparse".

I think that this is because the Python environment that the Linux shell is using does not have the argparse library in it, and I think I can fix it fix it if I can find the directories for the libraries being used by the Python environment, and copy the argparse library into it, but I can not find where that directory is located.

I would appreciate any help on finding this directory (I suppose I could include the argparse library in the same directory as my python script for now, but I would much rather have the argparse library in the place where the other Python libraries are, as it should be).

Comment: argparse.py is a pretty standard piece of python, it's possible that you've corrupted your sys.path. Please run this command and paste the result into your question: python -c "import argparse; print argparse"

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The `argparse` module was added in Python 2.7.
http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

Prior to 2.7, the most common way to handle command-line arguments was probably `getopt`.
http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html

Of course you can always handle the command-line manually simply by looking at `sys.argv`.  However `getopt` is a good abstraction layer, and `argparse` is even better.

If you truly need `argparse` in older environments (debatable), there is a Google Code project maintaining it, and you can include that in your project.  http://code.google.com/p/argparse/

Comment: Prior to 2.7, [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module could be used or `pip install argparse`.

Comment: @greg you can use `virtualenv` which includes `pip`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on CentOS and don't have an easy RPM to get to Python 2.7, JF's suggestion of `pip install argparse` is the way to go.  Calling out this solution in a new answer.  Thanks, JF.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the package manually if your using Centos 6 default Python 2.6.6

```
yum install python-argparse
```

Thats all it took for me to get IPython to work. Odd that YUM didnt install it automatically when I used YUM to install IPython.

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the search path for modules with:

```
import sys
print "\n".join(sys.path)
```

But not having argparse is odd: it's in the standard library...

Comment: Not in standard lib until 2.7.   See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an older version of Python.

The argparse module has been added pretty recently, in Python 2.7.